# Unable to get access token for a salesforce app

Tags: c#, oauth, salesforce

I am trying to get access token using OAuth for a salesforce account.I have Consumer Key and Consumer Secret Below is my code. But it throws an exception when it calls the method UsernamePasswordAsync. Please help me around this issue.

```
private static async Task RunSample()
        {
            try
            {
                var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
                // Authenticate with Salesforce
                Console.WriteLine("Authenticating with Salesforce");
                var url = IsSandboxUser.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    ? "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token "
                    : "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

                await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password, url);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Salesforce");
                var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);
                // retrieve all accounts
                Console.WriteLine("Get Accounts");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
The exception I am getting is 
Exception: **authentication failure**
Error:Salesforce.Common.Models.Error.InvalidGrant
Stack Trace:
   at Salesforce.Common.AuthenticationClient.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at SalesForceAuthSample.Program.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Pankaj Dalvi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MVP\SalesForceAuthSample\SalesForceAuthSample\Program.cs:line 65

Comment: Add the exception to your post.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without the content of the exception..

Comment: I get the same error, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are sure you have all of your credentials correct - the next item that I would check is your OAuth Policy listed in the Edit Menu of your Connected App. For the username-password OAuth flow, I believe this needs to be set to `All users may self-authorize`.

The other option, `Admin approved users are pre-authorized` doesn't seem to make sense in the username-password flow, e.g. there is no approval step from the user when using the username-password flow. The other two flow types, webserver flow and user agent flow, do have an approval step. Salesforce's [Edit Connected App Behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_manage_edit.htm) has more details.